# hypothesis test with known sigma in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, data-science, statsmodels

[image]

How can I perform a `ttest_ind` when I know the population variance of both samples in Python?  How can I specify those?  I couldn't find a solution.
It will be possible to do with `DescrStatsW` too?
I checked the `ttest_ind` documentation and I could only observe the `equal_var` parameter but it only serves when my sigma its unknown.
I tried both libraries (`scipy` and `statsmodels`) but I couldn't find the answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the population variances then you probably want to use a [z-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test) rather than a [t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test).

If somehow you know the variances of populations A and B but the means of those populations are unknown, then you could draw a sample from each population and test the hypothesis that the two populations have the same mean.  A z-test could be used if each population follows a normal distribution.

In many circumstances the variances of populations A and B are *unknown*, and we need to estimate those variances from the data samples.  That's what the t-test is for.  A t-test would not usually be appropriate if the population variances are known.